# Запуск Тестов на нескольких браузерах Selenium + NUnit

Tags: c#, selenium, test-automation, nunit

учусь писать автотесты, стал вопрос как запустить параллельное выполнение тестов на нескольких браузерах(допустим на 4х), если использовать многопоточность то как? Или уже заранее есть готовые инструменты? 
Пишу на C#, использую Selenium + NUnit.